# Use a variable on a script command line when its value isn't set until after the script starts

Tags: bash, variables

How to correctly pass to the script and substitute a variable that is already defined there?
My script test.sh:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
   
TARGETARCH=amd64

echo $1
```

When I enter:

```bash
bash test.sh https://example/$TARGETARCH
```

I want to see

```
https://example/amd64
```

but I actually see

```bash
https://example/
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The substitution happens __before the script is started__. Your script has no way of knowing that `$TARGETARCH` was ever there, because it's already long since gone.

Comment: (one of the things that's different between Windows and UNIX worlds is that Windows programs parse their own command lines, so they can see how the command was originally written. That's not true on UNIX: Programs are started with arrays of C strings an arguments; if there even _was_ an original command line string, the program being started is never given a chance to see it; see `man execve` for the low-level details).

Comment: Now, if you'd be okay with `bash test.sh 'https://example/$TARGETARCH'`, then the quotes stop `$TARGETARCH` from being expanded and removed by the calling shell, so it's still there when the child is started, so it becomes _possible_ to make the child expand it itself. If you're okay with that, indicate as much and we can provide an answer.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for your answers!:) Yes, I'm completely satisfied with `bash test.sh 'https://example/$TARGETARCH'`  My ultimate goal is to get an answer, is it possible in the end to get the desired result `https://example/amd64`

Comment: Certainly the above solution does what you want... although style wise, it's not what unix programmers expect to see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem with the original approach is that the `$TARGETARCH` is removed *by your calling shell* before your script is ever invoked. To prevent that, you need to use quotes:

```
./yourscript 'https://example.com/$TARGETARCH'
```

The second problem is that parameter expansions only happen in *code*, not in *data*. This is, from a security perspective, a Very Good Thing -- if data were silently treated as code it would be impossible to write secure scripts handling untrusted data -- but it does mean you need to do some more work. The *easy* thing, in this case, is to `export` your variable and use GNU `envsubst`, as long as your operating system provides it:

```
#!/bin/bash
export TARGETARCH=amd64

substitutedValue=$(envsubst <<<"$1")

echo "Original value was: $1"
echo "Substituted value is: $substitutedValue"
```

See the above running in an online sandbox at https://replit.com/@CharlesDuffy2/EcstaticAfraidComputeranimation#replit.nix

---

<sub>Note the use of `yourscript` instead of `test.sh` here -- using `.sh` file extensions, especially for *bash* scripts as opposed to *sh* scripts, is an antipattern; the essay at [https://www.talisman.org/~erlkonig/documents/commandname-extensions-considered-harmful/](https://www.talisman.org/%7Eerlkonig/documents/commandname-extensions-considered-harmful/) has been linked by the #bash IRC channel on this topic for over a decade.</sub>

<sub>For similar reasons, changing `bash yourscript` to `./yourscript` lets the `#!/usr/bin/env bash` line select an interpreter, so you aren't repeating the "bash" name in multiple places, leading to the risk of those places getting out of sync with each other.</sub>